# How to pass TextBox value to DynamicPopulateExtender query?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi I am trying to do DynamicPopulate on DropDownList2 when the value of textbox2 changes, how can I pass the value to TextBox2 to the sql query of DynamicPopulate.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
          DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
          onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MYDB %>" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT Time FROM Tour WHERE (Date = TextBox2 )">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
      <asp:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="DropDownList2_DynamicPopulateExtender" 
          runat="server" Enabled="True" PopulateTriggerControlID="" 
          TargetControlID="DropDownList2">
      </asp:DynamicPopulateExtender>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this javascript code to your page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateControl(value) {
    var behavior = $find('dp1');
    if (behavior)   {
         behavior.populate(value);   
        }
    }
    </script>
```

and use this modified code:

```
  <asp:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="DropDownList2_DynamicPopulateExtender" 
      runat="server" Enabled="True" PopulateTriggerControlID="" 
      TargetControlID="DropDownList2" BehaviorID="dp1">
  </asp:DynamicPopulateExtender>
```

in code behind of your vb or C# page make sure to add the attribute

```
    DropDownList2.Attributes.Add("onChange", "UpdateControl3(this.value);")
```

This will trigger the WebMethod for your DynamicPopulateExtender and will set the contextKey to the value of your dropdown.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused about what a `DynamicPopulateExtender` is used for. It's meant to return HTML from a call to a webservice when you change the value of a control on the page. It works with straight HTML, you don't use it to update other server controls on your page. I think what you're looking for is the `CascadingDropDown`, see http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx for more details.